# Java Refactoring - Can I move an interface into a new base class without updating all references to it?

Tags: java, inheritance

Assume I start with code like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public interface SomeInterface {
    int doSomething();
  }
}
```

Then I refactor it to look like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
  public interface SomeInterface {
    int doSomething();
  }
}

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
}
```

Now assume that there are many instances of MyClass in the code base. After the refactor, I want to avoid needing to update all references of MyClass.SomeInterface to BaseClass.SomeInterface. Is there a clean, easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ, the best approach will be to put the cursor on top of `MyClass` and press `shift + f6`. That key combination will rename all occurrences of the class.
After that, you just simply add the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me. I'm working at a giant corporation, and there are many, many places that use this interface in many repositories... I'm attempting to split functionality into multiple classes, since I have something that needs to be done that is very similar to the already existing class, but with small differences.

Comment: I totally understand you. I have a similar situation. In my case, I went ahead and I changed everything. It was worth it.
If you can't change everything, can you add a new method to do what you want?

Comment: The problem is that the new class shouldn't have 50% of the behavior in the original class. So I'd like to take the common code, move it into a base class, and then have 2 derived classes for the 2 cases. But the interface should be in the base class, since it is common. But it seems I cant then do: MyClass.SomeInterface if I do that...

Comment: Right, you won't be able to do that since the interface won't be under that class. What if you move the interface to its own file? That should solve the problem, but you will have to rename all the calls.